# JUnit Test runs only once

Tags: testing, gradle, groovy, junit

I have a simple JUnit test.
If I run it everything works fine. If I try to run it right after the last time it's just ignoring the test and finish without doing the test. When I'm waiting a while, like 5 minutes, then it works fine again until I try to run it right after that try.

For my test I'm using groovy with gradle and it's a gebish test.

Is there somewhere a "trigger" that I have to change that I can run the test every time I want?

This is my testcase:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4)
class TestClass extends GebReportingTest {
    @Test
    void justATest() {
        go "http://stackoverflow.com"

        assert $("#h-top-questions").text() == "Top Questions"

        go "http://google.com"
    }
}
```

And this is my build.gradle:

```
def browserstackUsername = ""
def browserstackKey = ""

apply plugin: 'groovy'


def gebVersion = '0.13.1'
def seleniumVersion = '2.51.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gebish:geb-gradle:0.13.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-gradle:$gebVersion"

    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"

    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
}

task firefoxTest(type: Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("$name/geb")
    systemProperty "geb.env", "firefox"
}

task browserstackTest(type: Test){
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("$name/geb")
    systemProperty "geb.env", "browserstack"

    apply plugin: "geb-browserstack"

    // Config: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#geb-browserstack-plugin
    browserStack {
        def applicationAddresses = [8000, 8080, 8888, 9000, 9090].collect { "http://localhost:$it" }
        application(*applicationAddresses)

        forceLocal = true
        browsers {
            firefox_windows
        }
        account {
            username = browserstackUsername
            accessKey = browserstackKey
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have just run the test, and the test passed, and you haven't changed anything, then the test will be skipped as it will obviously pass again

Comment: Why obviously? The webpage can change the whole time. And what about I'm checking a log that is changing the whole time? Because of this I'm looking for a solution to turn off the skipping.

Comment: A "clean build" should run the test again, but that would also rebuild your project - there is a way to make a task always "not up-to-date" in your Gradle build, but I don't remember how at this time.